# Pandas column replace multiple special characters and insert new characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, series

I have a pandas dataframe like  as below

```
Country_list

{'INDIA': '98.31%', 'ASEAN': '1.69%'}
{'KOREA': '100.0%'}
{'INDIA': '95.00%', 'ASEAN': '2.50%','ANZ': '2.50%'}
{'INDIA': '95.00%', 'ASEAN': '2.50%','ANZ': '1.25%','KOREA': '1.25%'}
```

I would like to do the below

a) Replace all numbers and special characters with '' (no blanks)

b) insert new character - Comma between different region names

I tried the below but this doesn't seem efficient or elegant

```
df['Country_list'] = df['Country_list'].str.replace(r":",'', regex=True).str.replace(r"%", '', regex=True).str.replace(r"{",'', regex=True).str.replace(r"}",'', regex=True)
```

I expect my output to be like as below

```
INDIA,ASEAN
KOREA
INDIA,ASEAN,ANZ
INDIA,ASEAN,ANZ,KOREA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need join keys of dictionaries by `,` convert strings to dictionaries and join keys in list comprehension:

```
import ast

df['Country_list'] = [','.join(ast.literal_eval(x).keys()) for x in df['Country_list']]
print (df)
            Country_list
0            INDIA,ASEAN
1                  KOREA
2        INDIA,ASEAN,ANZ
3  INDIA,ASEAN,ANZ,KOREA
```

Alternative solution:

```
import ast

f = lambda x: ','.join(ast.literal_eval(x).keys())
df['Country_list'] = df['Country_list'].apply(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have string representations of dictionaries, you could use a regex with [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html), then [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
df['Country_list'] = (df['Country_list'].str.extractall("'([^']+)':")[0]
                      .groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
                      )
```

Output:

```
            Country_list
0            INDIA,ASEAN
1                  KOREA
2        INDIA,ASEAN,ANZ
3  INDIA,ASEAN,ANZ,KOREA
```

For fun, another (hacky) solution based on a dot product:

```
import ast
tmp = pd.json_normalize(df['Country_list'].apply(ast.literal_eval))

df['Country_list'] = tmp.notna().dot(tmp.columns+',').str[:-1]
```

Output:

```
            Country_list
0            INDIA,ASEAN
1                  KOREA
2        INDIA,ASEAN,ANZ
3  INDIA,ASEAN,KOREA,ANZ
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this way:

```
print(df['Country_list'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.keys())))
```

output:

```
0              INDIA,ASEAN
1                    KOREA
2          INDIA,ASEAN,ANZ
3    INDIA,ASEAN,ANZ,KOREA
```